# jQuery CSS Conflict with Bootstrap CSS

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I have implemented [Xdsoft](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) Datetime Picker in my ready mate template site which is using bootstrap. But the design of the datetimepicker gets spoiled due to conflict with bootstrap css.

When I commented the bootstrap css its obvious the theme gets spoiled but the datetimepicker works perfect then.

How should I overcome this?

Comment: Not PHP related, more like CSS :)

Comment: make online demo, to inspect your code correctly

Comment: Try loading the CSS files in reverse order.

Comment: I have already tried that @rybo111

Comment: Figure out what CSS is getting overridden then resolve. It's hard to provide an accurate answer without a live example somewhere to debug.

Comment: I had the same problem a week ago. It's due to bootstrap's tables CSS rules. You have to edit your Bootstrap CSS to avoid impacting datepicker or override them in a CSS loaded after the bootStrap stylesheet. For more details, you can also use a plugin like FireBug, which allow you to see in what way rules are overridding pervious rules, eso...